# Giving image ref to the specific text in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, text, textview

Is it possible to give an reference of a image to the specific text. **For Example** If a sentence in a textview is **I love India** and I want to show the image when I touch the text **India**. The image will be present in another drawer named image gallery. 
Im using navigation drawer using fragments , help me how can i do it.

Comment: Do you need different images for different words? For example, if you press "I love" it redirects to an image and "India" to another image?

Comment: Please clarify your question and provide code samples

Comment: @ricardosilva yes sir, different text will redirect to different image, I know the concept of ClickableSpan but don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is [ClickableSpan](http://www.androidgig.com/part-of-textview-clickable/). Once you have different parts of the text clickable, then you can link your image logic to it